# Why does this generic cast fail?

Tags: .net, generics, casting, ienumerable

I have the following inheritance:

```
internal abstract class TeraRow{}

internal class xRow : TeraRow {} // xRow is a child of TeraRow

public IEnumerable<TeraRow> Compare(MappedTables which, DateTime selectionStart
        , DateTime selectionEnd, string pwd)
{
    IEnumerable<xRow> result=CompareX();
    return  (IEnumerable<TeraRow>)result; //Invalid Cast Exception? 

}
```

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[xRow]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TeraRow]

Also why do I need to cast it at all?

Comment: This type of cast will be supported in C# 4.0, being released later this year.  The feature that addresses this issue is called covariant generic arguments.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to cast it because `IEnumerable<T>` is not covariant on T.  You can do this:

```
return result.Cast<TeraRow>();
```

Comment: Downcasting generic-typed lists... One of the few places where generics fall apart without explicitly defining composite interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

See this question: [.NET Casting Generic List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674715/net-casting-generic-list)

Answer (score 2):

You're running afoul of contravariance.  You'd need c# 4.0 for that to work.  The type IEnumerable can't be exchanged for IEnumerable in 2.0 to 3.5. The msdn article on it is http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Covariance+and+Contravariance/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you need the casted list to perform like the original reference (setting an item at an index also sets the item in the original collection, you can create a wrapper class that implements IList<T>. (Unless I'm missing something), for a general purpose solution you'll need two due to generic constraint limitations:

```
public class UpCastList<FromType, ToType> : IList<ToType>
    where FromType : ToType

public class DownCastList<FromType, ToType : IList<ToType>
    where ToType : FromType
```

The other possibility is delegating the conversion:

```
public class CastList<FromType, ToType> : IList<ToType>
{
    public CastList(IList<FromType> source, Func<FromType, ToType> converter) { ... }
}
```

Edit: if you only need an IEnumerable<T>, then you can use the Cast<T> extension method as mentioned earlier.