# Casting generic classes in C#

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a problem with casting generic types.

For example I have classes:

```
public class Dog
{
}

public class Husky : Dog
{

}

public class MyWrapper<T> where T : class
{
}
```

and then I want to do something like this, but I don't know how

```
MyWrapper<Husky> husky = new MyWrapper<Husky>();
List<MyWrapper<Dog>> dogs= new List<MyWrapper<Dog>>();
dogs.Add(husky); // how to cast husky to MyWrapper<Dog>?
```

EDIT: Changed `Animal<T>` to `MyWrapper<T>`, so it will be more adequate example

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [generic covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) of interfaces in C# 4 or later. In order to do so, you'd need to define a covariant interface (using `out`) and have `MyWrapper` implement that interface:

```
public class Dog 
{
}

public class Husky : Dog
{
}

public class MyWrapper<T> : IMyWrapper<T> where T : class
{
}

public interface IMyWrapper<out T> where T : class
{
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
var husky = new MyWrapper<Husky>();
var dogs = new List<IMyWrapper<Dog>>();
dogs.Add(husky);
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid you can't - although `Husky` is a `Dog`, `Animal<Husky>` is not an `Animal<Dog>`.

See [.NET Casting Generic List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674715/net-casting-generic-list) for a similar question.

Comment: +1. Generally, generics inherit from their generic type and THAT IS IT - the hierarchy of parameters is not preserved. That also makes sense as it may not always be possible to do so (with multiple parameters).

Answer (score 6):

Any reason why you would not arrange your class inheritance as follows? I am not sure why Animal needs to accept a type parameter.

```
public abstract class Animal
{
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
}

public class Husky : Dog 
{
}
```

Comment: Agree, thugh I can only say - he made a decent EXAMPLE and as such it should stand. If that would be a real class hiearchy, it IS an abuse of generics instead of simple inheritance, as you point out.

Answer (score 5):

You need **covariance** for that - *upcasting a generic type* -.

But C# covariance is only supported on:

- Delegates.
- Interfaces.

For that reason, I only find a solution: **create a marker interface `IAnimal<T>`**:

```
public class Dog
{
}

public class Husky : Dog
{

}

public interface IAnimal<out T>
    where T : class
{
}

public class Animal<T> : IAnimal<T> where T : class
{
}
```

And now this will work:

```
        List<IAnimal<Dog>> list = new List<IAnimal<Dog>>();
        list.Add(new Animal<Husky>());
```

Learn more about covariance and contravariance on MSDN:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

### UPDATE

Anyway... what's the point of the generic constraint `T : class`? You only know that `T` is a class, but it could have no public constructor, or it could be a rock instead of a dog, who knows?

Or, what's the point of this class hierarchy? As other have pointed out in their answers, your hierarchy isn't very object-oriented-ish: a Dog **IS an animal** so `Dog` **DERIVES** `Animal`.

Just changing that, you've lost the need of using generic type parameters.

Maybe you prefer composition over inheritance, but I tend to decide what's best with this question:

- If I talk about the specialized type, can I say "B is A"? => **Then I choose inheritance**.
- If I talk about the specialized type, can I say "B is part of A" => **Then I choose composition**.

**Actually I believe that covariance solves your question, but I feel it's a wrong use case of this language feature.**

Comment: It works, thanks! In my project there is something like `class Wrapper<T>` so it won't be inherited by classes of type T. Sorry, my example with Animal<T> was unfortunate. But thanks for resolving my problem anyway.

Comment: @vanilla161 Yeah, I thought that (the thing about the wrapper), but I had to answer to your actual question's text :(

Answer (score 2):

not possible `Animal<Husky>` is not derived from `Animal<Dog>`.